# Laravel collection pluck dropping a value

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following `Eloquent` query in a `Laravel 5.2` project:

```
$regsByCtryCollection = Organisation::join('countries_currencies', 'countries_currencies.id', '=', 'organisations.country_id')
   ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT LCASE(countries_currencies.country_code) AS ctry, COUNT(organisations.id) AS val'))
   ->groupBy('ctry')
   ->get();
```

The raw query produces this output:

```
ctry val
at   1
au   5
br   1
```

The `Eloquent` call produces a collection of three rows (matching raw query output) like this:

```
Collection {#791 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Organisation {#777 ▼
      #table: "organisations"
      #hidden: []
      ........
      #attributes: array:2 [▶]
      #original: array:2 [▼
        "ctry" => "at"
        "val" => 1
      ]
      #relations: array:5 [▶]
      ........
    }
    1 => Organisation {#778 ▶}
    2 => Organisation {#779 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I then pluck the values and format for `Highmaps` like this

```
$regsByCtry = $regsByCtryCollection->pluck('ctry', 'val')->map(function($country, $value) {
   return [
       "hc-key" => $country,
        "value"  => $value
   ];
})->values()->toJson();
```

And one of the values is dropped and I get this:

```
[
    {"hc-key":"br","value":1},
    {"hc-key":"au","value":5}
]
```

Why is the first entry getting dropped?

```
{"hc-key":"at","value":1}
```

I am using this same process with two other `Eloquent` queries and it works as expected, but just not on this collection.

Additionally, I also sum all the values in the array of objects like this:

```
$regsTotal = array_sum($regsByCtryCollection->pluck('val')->toArray());
```

And I get the correct value, including all three records summed:

```
$regsTotal = 7;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `pluck('ctry', 'val')`. This will return `val` as key & `ctry` as value. In your query output `at` & `br` has same value `1`. So one of it getting replaced by the other one.

Try `pluck('val', 'ctry')->map(function($value, $country)`

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: Rock n roll! Thank you!